# Modbus Python and Temperature & DO sensor

Tags: python, serial-communication, modbus

I have a problem related to read a Temperature & Disolved Oxygen (DO) from a RTU sensor working under RS485 protocol.

I already tried with C++ and C# to do this, but the response is very confusing and wrong, so i decided to give it a try to Python with the default MinimalModbus lib. (All the codes have been developed in Linux enviroment).

I need to write the following bytes array to get the Temperature measurement and DO measurements, according to the sensor manual:

```
byte[] start_command = {0x01, 0x03, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4E, 0xc6} //START MEASUREMENT COMMAND

byte[] = {0x01, 0x03, 0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x4F, 0x41} //READ TEMP & DO COMMAND
```

where the first byte would be the device address, the second byte the command (READ COMMAND).

```
byte[] stop_command = {0x01, 0x03, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C, 0xe2} //STOP MEASUREMENT COMMAND
```

So eventually the sensor will reply the Temperature data in the 3-6 bytes and also the DO measurement in the 7-10 bytes from the frame

The formal sensor's specification are (from manual):

**Coding system:** 8 bit binary (Each 8-bit package contains 4-bit hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F)

**Bit per byte:** 1 start bit, 8 data bits (least significant bit first), No parity check, 2 stop bits

**Baud rate:** 9600bps

The following code in python is the one I'm trying to connect to this device:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import minimalmodbus

import serial


instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.3:1.0-port0', 1, minimalmodbus.MODE_ASCII) # port name, slave address (in decimal), type
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
instrument.serial.stopbits = 2
instrument.serial.timeout = 1.5
instrument.debug = True
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
print instrument

temp = instrument.read_float(0, functioncode=0x03,
    numberOfRegisters=2)
print "Temperatura: ", temp
```

The output is the following:

```
minimalmodbus.Instrument<id=0x7f0267d40c20, address=1, mode=rtu, close_port_after_each_call=False, precalculate_read_size=True, debug=True, serial=Serial<id=0x7f0267d37f10, open=True>(port='/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2.3:1.0-port0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=2, timeout=1.5, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)>

MinimalModbus debug mode. Writing to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xc4\x0b' (01 03 00 00 00 02 C4 0B)
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1449073891873.3 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x00\x7f~\xfe\xfe\xf6\xeez' (00 7F 7E FE FE F6 EE 7A) (8 bytes), roundtrip time: 1511.2 ms. Timeout setting: 1500.0 ms.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 17, in <module>
    numberOfRegisters=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 392, in read_float
    return self._genericCommand(functioncode, registeraddress, numberOfRegisters=numberOfRegisters, payloadformat='float')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 697, in _genericCommand
    payloadFromSlave = self._performCommand(functioncode, payloadToSlave)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 798, in _performCommand
    payloadFromSlave = _extractPayload(response, self.address, self.mode, functioncode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1075, in _extractPayload
    raise ValueError(text)
ValueError: Checksum error in rtu mode: '\xeez' instead of '\xac/' . The response is: '\x00\x7f~\xfe\xfe\xf6\xeez' (plain response: '\x00\x7f~\xfe\xfe\xf6\xeez')
```

The first problem that I see, is that the wroten command was:

```
\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xc4\x0b
```

when should be:

```
\x01\x03\x26\x00\x00\x04\x4F\x41
```

Unfortunatelly I dont know how to change this frame.

The other problem is that I need to send first the START COMMAND and at the end the STOP COMMAND before specified.

Please any help will be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a place in your Python code where you actually pass the start command anywhere?

Comment: No, exactly that's the second problem that I have. I dont know how to do so. The commands to write provided by minimalmodbus, specifies 16-bit commands or 32-bit. When I'm using 13 bits I dont know how to do this, or if it's actually the same.
See : http://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apiminimalmodbus.html